# How do I use a variable as a Property Identifier?

Tags: c#

In my specific example, I am using the [Control.ModifierKeys Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys?view=netframework-4.8) and have something like:

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
{
    // some code
}
```

But say I want that "Shift" to be able to be changed via variable, like:

```
private string myKey = "Shift"
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.myKey)
{
    // some code
}
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare enums with strings by calling `ToString()`:

```
private string myKey = "Shift"
if (Keyboard.Modifiers.ToString() == myKey)
{
    // some code
}
```

But a more type-safe way would be to hold an enum value in a variable:

```
private Keys myKey = ModifierKeys.Shift;
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == myKey)
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that and plugin a variable value as enum constant. You can directly compare your string key like

```
private string myKey = "Shift"
if (Keyboard.Modifiers.ToString() == myKey)
{
    // some code
}
```